# How to scan process capabilities

Tags: linux-capabilities

I would like to see the Linux capabilities of running processes.

Comment: Please visit the How to Ask page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out what linux capabilities a process requires to work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35469038/how-to-find-out-what-linux-capabilities-a-process-requires-to-work)

Comment: https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/captree

Answer (score 2):

```
ps -ef |awk {'print $2'} | xargs getpcaps
```