# How to find out what Linux capabilities a process requires to work?

Tags: linux, debugging, linux-kernel, linux-capabilities

I am in a difficult situation where I don't know what Linux capabilities a process requires to work.

What is the best way, or any way, to find out what capability is required?

The only thing I can think of right now is using [`capsh`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/capsh.1.html) and drop all capabilities on a process. The process then fails and I start to add capabilities (by removing `--drop=CAP_XZY`) until it works.

Any better suggestions?

Comment: I'd expect the installer to configure the required capabilities.

Comment: Maybe if you explained exactly what the process does...?

Comment: @Paul ok let's make a concrete exmaple:
`# capsh --drop=cap_net_raw -- -c "ping localhost"
ping: icmp open socket: Operation not permitted`
In this case, i drop the cap required for ping and then execute a ping. Of course, it doesn't work. Given this scenario, how do I find out that ping needs cap_net_raw? There are situation where a process does something that requires a specific cap. How can I found out which one?

Comment: Did you write the program?  If so, you should know what capabilities it needs.  If not, then it's a sysadmin question rather than a programming one.

Comment: Yes, if only there was something like selinux' permissive mode.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

### Based on recent libcap2 update

#### 1: (Short option):  *getpcaps*

**Description:**

From [here](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/getpcaps.8.html):

> getpcaps displays the capabilities on the processes indicated by the
> pid value(s) given on the command line.

**Example:**

```
$ getpcaps <PID>
PID: = cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap+i
```

---

#### 2: (A bit longer option): */proc status and capsh*

**Description:**

[proc](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) is a process information pseudo-filesystem or in other words - a directory where you can view information on all processes.

About [capsh](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/capsh.1.html):

> Linux capability support and use can be explored and constrained with
> this tool. This tool provides a handy wrapper for certain types of
> capability testing and environment creation. 
>  It also provides
> some debugging features useful for summarizing capability state.

**Example:**

```
$ cat /proc/<PID>/status | grep Cap
```

And you'll get (on most systems):

```
CapInh: 00000000a80425fb (Inherited capabilities)
CapPrm: 0000000000000000 (Permitted capabilities)
CapEff: 0000000000000000 (Effective capabilities)
CapBnd: 00000000a80425fb (Bounding set)
CapAmb: 000000000000000  (Ambient capabilities set)
```

Use the `capsh` utility to decode from hexadecimal numbers into the capabilities name:

```
capsh --decode=00000000a80425fb
0x00000000a80425fb=cap_chown,cap_dac_override,cap_fowner,cap_fsetid,cap_kill,cap_setgid,cap_setuid,cap_setpcap,cap_net_bind_service,cap_net_raw,cap_sys_chroot,cap_mknod,cap_audit_write,cap_setfcap
```

(*) You can download `capsh` with: `sudo apt-get install git libpcap-dev`.

Comment: Thanks @RtmY. Greate update on recent libcap2 development. Btw that's the source of getpcaps: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/libs/libcap/libcap.git/

Comment: See also `capsh --print`

Comment: You might also like to checkout [`captree`](https://sites.google.com/site/fullycapable/captree) which might help you understand the relationship between processes and threads that are trying to use capabilities in your system.

Comment: For a one-liner, I'm doing something like this to inspect effective capabilities of a PID: `gawk '/^CapEff/ {print $2}' /proc/<PID>/status | xargs -n1 -I {} capsh --decode={}`

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the original question. Using this method you will get the current capabilities for a particular process, but if you run the process dropping all capabilities, using something like this `capsh --drop=all --print -- -c "/usr/bin/ping -c 4 8.8.8.8" ` you won't find the specific capability that we are looking for, which is `cap_net_raw`

Comment: I think that the answer provides 2 different ways for "How to find out what linux capabilities a process requires to work?" Plus it was verified by the origin questioner.

Answer (score 19):

Turns out it is easier than expected. Install libcap-ng (https://people.redhat.com/sgrubb/libcap-ng/) and use `pscap`.

In Ubuntu 16.04, it can be installed with:

```
sudo apt-get install libcap-ng-utils
```

Sample output excerpt:

Run command: `netcap`

```
ppid  pid   name        command           capabilities
1     468   root        systemd-journal   chown, dac_override, dac_read_search, fowner, setgid, setuid, sys_ptrace, sys_admin, audit_control, mac_override, syslog, audit_read
1     480   root        lvmetad           full
1     492   root        systemd-udevd     full
1     1040  root        rpc.idmapd        full
1     1062  root        rpc.gssd          full
1     1184  messagebus  dbus-daemon       audit_write +
1     1209  root        NetworkManager    dac_override, kill, setgid, setuid, net_bind_service, net_admin, net_raw, sys_module, sys_chroot, audit_write
```

Comment: This is not working for python processes, is there a way to list which capabilities a python process requires?

Comment: @belabrinel yes it works for all process/binaries, `pscap -a` will list all

Answer (score 19):

Another method, that I've come across a while ago in this [blog post by Brendan Gregg](http://www.brendangregg.com/blog/2016-10-01/linux-bcc-security-capabilities.html) is to use capabilities tracer - *capable*.

Below is a sample output:

```
$ sudo /usr/share/bcc/tools/capable
TIME      UID    PID    COMM             CAP  NAME                 AUDIT
11:31:54  0      2467   capable          21   CAP_SYS_ADMIN        1
11:31:54  0      2467   capable          21   CAP_SYS_ADMIN        1
11:31:59  1000   2468   ls               1    CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE     1
11:31:59  1000   2468   ls               2    CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH  1
11:32:02  0      1421   timesync         25   CAP_SYS_TIME         1
11:32:05  1000   2469   sudo             7    CAP_SETUID           1
11:32:05  0      2469   sudo             6    CAP_SETGID           1
```

It has a significant advantage of recording capability checks made by kernel for a given process. This allows to profile the application against the capabilities that it actually requires, e.g. to narrow down the privileges and execute it as an unprivileged user.

While *pscap* allows to list the **effective** capabilities of all running processes, it does not offer a reliable method of checking which capabilities are in fact required by the process, because:

- A process may have capability X in its permitted set and only raise it to the effective set for a short time to perform a privileged operation.
- A process could have started with broader set of capabilities, do the initialization requiring elevated privileges, and drop some (or all) capabilities (e.g. [ping opening a raw socket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46059187/why-is-capeff-all-zeros-in-proc-pid-status)).
- It works only for processes that are already running in capabilities-based manner. What if you had to determine the minimal capability set required for your newly developed application?
- It does not allow to correlate privilege checks made for application with the operations it performs, with *capable* you get timestamps for ever single check.

The sources for *capable* are available on [github](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/tools/capable.py). Installation instructions for BCC (including *capable*) are available [here](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/INSTALL.md).
For further description please refer to the blog post mentioned at the beginning, please also note that capable requires kernel 4.4+, an alternative for older kernels is available in the blog post as well.

Note: I'm not the author, nor am I affiliated with the tool developers in any way. I just wanted to bring it to wider audience, since I have personally used it to develop a capabilities profile for a complex monitoring application that previously required full root privileges to run, and found this tracer to be of tremendous help.

Answer (score 1):

I did this: drop all capabilities, and re-enable them one by one (just by commenting out a line) and retrying the script.

It's a bit hit-and-miss to guess the CAP which causes the failure.

```
#!/bin/bash
D="cap_audit_control"
D="${D},cap_audit_read"
D="${D},cap_audit_write"
D="${D},cap_block_suspend"
D="${D},cap_chown"
D="${D},cap_dac_override"
D="${D},cap_dac_read_search"
D="${D},cap_fowner"
D="${D},cap_fsetid"
D="${D},cap_ipc_lock"
D="${D},cap_ipc_owner"
D="${D},cap_kill"
D="${D},cap_lease"
D="${D},cap_linux_immutable"
D="${D},cap_mac_admin"
D="${D},cap_mac_override"
D="${D},cap_mknod"
D="${D},cap_net_admin"
D="${D},cap_net_bind_service"
D="${D},cap_net_broadcast"
D="${D},cap_net_raw"
D="${D},cap_setfcap"
D="${D},cap_setgid"
D="${D},cap_setpcap"
D="${D},cap_setuid"
D="${D},cap_sys_admin"
D="${D},cap_sys_boot"
D="${D},cap_sys_chroot"
D="${D},cap_syslog"
D="${D},cap_sys_module"
D="${D},cap_sys_nice"
D="${D},cap_sys_pacct"
D="${D},cap_sys_ptrace"
D="${D},cap_sys_rawio"
D="${D},cap_sys_resource"
D="${D},cap_sys_time"
D="${D},cap_sys_tty_config"
D="${D},cap_wake_alarm"
# capsh in debian package: libcap2-bin
/usr/sbin/capsh --drop=${D} -- -c 'ping -c 1 8.8.8.8'
```

Answer (score 0):

Further: to list syscalls associated with capabilities, I searched the provided manpages for mentions (this is obviously not an exhaustive list).

With a file 'caps' listing the 38 CAPS_* identiers:

```
$ head caps
CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL
CAP_AUDIT_READ
CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND
CAP_CHOWN
...
```

I can search like this (the '2' section of the manpages list syscalls):

```
$ find /usr/share/man/man2 -type f -name \*\.gz | while read M ; do zgrep -wf caps $M | tr -c 'A-Z_' '\n' | grep -wf caps | sort -u | sed "s|$| = $M|;s|/usr/share/man/man2/||;s|.2.gz||" ; done | sort -u

CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND = epoll_ctl
CAP_CHOWN = chown
CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE = mount
CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE = utime
CAP_DAC_OVERRIDE = utimensat
CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH = link
CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH = open
CAP_DAC_READ_SEARCH = open_by_handle_at
CAP_FOWNER = chmod
CAP_FOWNER = ioctl_iflags
CAP_FOWNER = open
CAP_FOWNER = rename
CAP_FOWNER = rmdir
CAP_FOWNER = unlink
CAP_FOWNER = utime
CAP_FOWNER = utimensat
CAP_FSETID = chmod
CAP_IPC_LOCK = mlock
CAP_IPC_LOCK = shmctl
CAP_IPC_LOCK = shmget
CAP_IPC_OWNER = msgctl
CAP_IPC_OWNER = msgget
CAP_IPC_OWNER = msgop
CAP_IPC_OWNER = semctl
CAP_IPC_OWNER = semget
CAP_IPC_OWNER = semop
CAP_IPC_OWNER = shmctl
CAP_IPC_OWNER = shmget
CAP_IPC_OWNER = shmop
CAP_KILL = kill
CAP_LEASE = fcntl
CAP_LINUX_IMMUTABLE = ioctl_iflags
CAP_MKNOD = mknod
CAP_MKNOD = rename
CAP_SETGID = clone
CAP_SETGID = getgroups
CAP_SETGID = seteuid
CAP_SETGID = setfsgid
CAP_SETGID = setgid
CAP_SETGID = setresuid
CAP_SETGID = setreuid
CAP_SETPCAP = capget
CAP_SETPCAP = prctl
CAP_SETUID = clone
CAP_SETUID = keyctl
CAP_SETUID = seteuid
CAP_SETUID = setfsuid
CAP_SETUID = setresuid
CAP_SETUID = setreuid
CAP_SETUID = setuid
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = bdflush
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = bpf
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = clone
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = fanotify_init
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = getdomainname
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = gethostname
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = getrlimit
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = ioctl_getfsmap
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = ioctl_tty
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = ioprio_set
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = io_submit
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = keyctl
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = lookup_dcookie
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = madvise
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = mount
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = msgctl
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = open_by_handle_at
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = pciconfig_read
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = perf_event_open
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = pivot_root
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = prctl
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = ptrace
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = quotactl
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = seccomp
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = semctl
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = setns
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = shmctl
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = swapon
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = syslog
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = umount
CAP_SYS_ADMIN = unshare
CAP_SYS_BOOT = kexec_load
CAP_SYS_BOOT = reboot
CAP_SYS_CHROOT = chroot
CAP_SYS_CHROOT = setns
CAP_SYSLOG = syslog
CAP_SYS_MODULE = create_module
CAP_SYS_MODULE = delete_module
CAP_SYS_MODULE = init_module
CAP_SYS_NICE = getpriority
CAP_SYS_NICE = ioprio_set
CAP_SYS_NICE = mbind
CAP_SYS_NICE = migrate_pages
CAP_SYS_NICE = move_pages
CAP_SYS_NICE = nice
CAP_SYS_NICE = sched_setaffinity
CAP_SYS_NICE = sched_setparam
CAP_SYS_NICE = spu_create
CAP_SYS_PACCT = acct
CAP_SYS_PTRACE = get_robust_list
CAP_SYS_PTRACE = kcmp
CAP_SYS_PTRACE = ptrace
CAP_SYS_PTRACE = userfaultfd
CAP_SYS_RAWIO = ioperm
CAP_SYS_RAWIO = iopl
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE = fcntl
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE = getrlimit
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE = ioctl_iflags
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE = msgctl
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE = msgop
CAP_SYS_RESOURCE = prctl
CAP_SYS_TIME = adjtimex
CAP_SYS_TIME = gettimeofday
CAP_SYS_TIME = stime
CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG = ioctl_console
CAP_SYS_TTY_CONFIG = vhangup
CAP_WAKE_ALARM = timer_create
CAP_WAKE_ALARM = timerfd_create
```

So the missing CAP_'s are:

```
$ cat syscap | cut -d' ' -f 1 | sort -u | grep -vwf - caps 
CAP_AUDIT_CONTROL
CAP_AUDIT_READ
CAP_AUDIT_WRITE
CAP_MAC_ADMIN
CAP_MAC_OVERRIDE
CAP_NET_ADMIN
CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
CAP_NET_BROADCAST
CAP_NET_RAW
CAP_SETFCAP
```

And only make mention of 88 of 347 syscalls on my system

```
$ cat syscap | cut -d' ' -f 3 | sort -u | wc -l
88
```