# Why is CapEff all zeros in /proc/$PID/status

Tags: linux, ping, linux-capabilities

I removed the setuid bit from the ping binary and added `cap_net_raw+p` instead as follows:

```
$ chmod 755 /bin/ping
$ setcap cap_net_raw+p /bin/ping
```

Then I ran `ping` in one terminal and checked the /proc/$PID/status of the running process from another:

```
$ ps aux | grep ping                                                                   
  user     5468  0.0  0.0  14948  1792 pts/20   S+   11:14   0:00 ping www.google.com
  user     5471  0.0  0.0  14224   896 pts/2    S+   11:14   0:00 grep --color=auto ping
$ cat /proc/5468/status | grep Cap
  CapInh: 0000000000000000
  CapPrm: 0000000000002000
  CapEff: 0000000000000000
  CapBnd: 0000003fffffffff
  CapAmb: 0000000000000000
```

If `ping` is currently running why is `CapEff: 0000000000000000`? Shouldn't `cap_net_raw` be in the effective set as well? Does /proc/$PID/status not reflect the **current** state of the thread?

Comment: Good question, good answer. Well done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A helpful person in #kernelnewbies on OFTC (irc) was kind enough to provide me with the answer.

`ping` sets `cap_net_raw` in the effective set, creates the socket, then drops `cap_net_raw`, as can been seen with strace:

```
$ strace -e socket,capset ping -c1 localhost
  capset({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {CAP_NET_RAW, CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW, 0}) = 0
  socket(PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_ICMP) = 3
  capset({_LINUX_CAPABILITY_VERSION_3, 0}, {0, CAP_NET_ADMIN|CAP_NET_RAW, 0}) = 0
```

Once the socket is open, no more privileges are required to write to it.

Comment: More precisely in `iputils/ping/ping.c` the `create_socket` calls are between `enable_capability_raw()` and `disable_capability_raw()` functions.