# How do i map linux system calls to capabilities

Tags: docker, system-calls, linux-capabilities

I want to run a container in un-privileged mode.This is in attempt to keep it more secure and for better control.I recorded few system calls from my container .
Below are the syscalls:

recvfrom

mmap

write

read

fstat

recvmsg

mprotect

munmap

socket

fcntl

io_submit

io_getevents

select

epoll_ctl

lseek

sendmsg

ioctl

stat

sendto

sched_yield

sysdigevent

rt_sigaction

How do I map above syscalls to capabilities?
I want to add those capabilities while running my container

Comment: Just do it. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities

Comment: I don't think you can, linux capabilities doesn't work on individual system call basis, and it works on adding more access to something that is unprivileged, but those system calls can already be done by unprivileged processes.

Comment: How can i find out which capabilities are required for my container to run in  un-privileged mode?

Comment: You can use capabilities traces like capable, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47991611/3147123

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `sysdigevent`, which I can't identify, the rest look like basic system calls. Unless you are operating on privileged sockets, raw block devices or anything else inherently privileged, you shouldn't need any capabilites.

Answer (score 0):

You can scan man pages for mentions of CAP_, which won't of course be conclusive.

```
LIST="epoll_ctl fcntl fstat io_getevents io_submit ioctl lseek mmap mprotect munmap read recvfrom recvmsg rt_sigaction sched_yield select sendmsg sendto socket stat sysdigevent write"
$ for S in $LIST ; do  \
   echo "syscall: $S" ; \
   man $S 2>/dev/null | grep "CAP_[A-Z]" | tr -s ' ' ;  \
done | grep -B 1 CAP
```

gives

```
syscall: epoll_ctl
    If EPOLLONESHOT and EPOLLET are clear and the process has the CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND capability, ensure that the system does not enter "suspend" or
    If EPOLLWAKEUP is specified in flags, but the caller does not have the CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND capability, then the EPOLLWAKEUP flag is silently ignored.
    of the EPOLLWAKEUP with a check that caused the call to fail if the caller did not have the CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND capability caused a breakage in at least
    it has the CAP_BLOCK_SUSPEND capability if attempting to use the EPOLLWAKEUP flag.
syscall: fcntl
    of the process. A process with the CAP_LEASE capability may take out leases on arbitrary files.
    /proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size yield the error EPERM; a privileged process (CAP_SYS_RESOURCE) can override the limit.
syscall: io_submit
    EPERM The aio_reqprio field is set with the class IOPRIO_CLASS_RT, but the submitting context does not have the CAP_SYS_ADMIN capability.
```